# What Is a "Fully Stalled" takeoff?

Tags: aerodynamics, takeoff, stall

Reading [this article](https://leehamnews.com/2019/11/01/a-basic-mcas-system-was-installed-in-the-boeing-707-in-the-1960s/) (on the Boeing 737 MAX saga; irrelevant), I found the following excerpt:

> Boeing ultimately accepted Davies recommendation and, we understand,
>   halted production of the 707 for 10-11 months, whilst a new fin was
>   designed and installed.  All existing 707s were then retrospectively
>   modified.  A ventral fin was also installed on some variants to
>   prevent ‘fully stalled take-offs’ which the Comet was also susceptible
>   to.

I tried to search, but I found nothing on "fully stalled take-offs", whether about the Comet or any other aircraft.

So, what is a "fully-stalled take-off"? Are some aerodynamic designs (or aircraft models) more susceptible to it?

Comment: Related: https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Take_Off_Stall

Comment: I understand the concept of stalling during (i.e. right after) take-off, but I'm having a hard time conceiving what a "fully stalled take-off" really is – in the context, I fail to see how "fully stalled" is different to "stalled", for instance.

Comment: The ventral fin was added to improve yaw stability.  It's implausible that it could inhibit stalling, of any kind, on the 707 or Comet or anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "fully-stalled take-off" is an attempted takeoff where the elevator has too much authority. This can cause the aircraft to rotate to an excessive nose up attitude, which can exceed the stall angle of attack, before takeoff speed is attained.

Ventral fins were added to some B707s to improve yaw control, and prevent over-rotation. Over rotation which could lead to a "full stall at takeoff".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707

> The British Air Registration Board refused to give the aircraft a certificate of airworthiness, citing insufficient yaw control, excessive rudder forces, and the ability to over-rotate on takeoff, stalling the wing on the ground (a fault of the de Havilland Comet 1). Boeing responded by adding 40 inches to the vertical stabilizer, applying full instead of partial rudder boost, **and fitting an underfin to prevent over-rotation**.

[image]

Comment: How does the ventral prevent over-rotation? Is it meant to serve as a geometric tail strike barrier?

Comment: Yes, it would be a physical barrier to over rotation.

Comment: So the idea is that FULL aft stick input (or however much it takes to strike the tail) may be allowed to result in a tail strike but must not result not a stalled attitude, as long the main wheels are still on the ground?  So the problem may be prevented either by a physical barrier or by limiting elevator authority?

Comment: @quietflyer  It's referred to as Vmu, minimum unstick speed, and is now required to be demonstrated for certification. In the case of early rotation the speed at which the last main gear leaves the ground.  The aircraft must then climb out without stall.  Here's a video of the [A380 Vmu test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7I6SSE88fF0).

Comment: The ventral fin would have improved _directional_ (yaw) stability, not _lateral_ (roll) stability.

Comment: @Sean You are correct andI have edited my answer.

Comment: @quietflyer reaching stall attitude is much more dangerous. If you scrape the tail, the damage will probably be expensive, but the aircraft will still lift off, so you can make a circuit and land back. But since stall only depends on angle of attack, if you exceed critical angle of attack, the aircraft will not lift off and if you don't correct quickly, you'll overrun the runway and crash. So it is better if the aircraft is geometrically limited.